# Laravel Envoy doesn't complete basic task on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.2, laravel-envoy

So I tried to use Laravel Envoy for the first time and run the example task as [described in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/envoy#writing-tasks).

```
@servers(['web' => 'redacted-user@redacted-ip'])

@task('foo', ['on' => 'web'])
ls -la
@endtask
```

---

```
envoy run foo
[✗] This task did not complete successfully on one of your servers.
```

I tried newer PHP binaries from the official website but that didn't fix it. When I do `envoy ssh` it works and regular SSH works too with the provided credentials (I can use user/password or publickey to login).

What could be stopping envoy from connecting and executing the task?

These are my settings:

- Windows 10
- PHP 7.2.11 (cli) (built: Oct 10 2018 02:04:07) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
- Laravel Envoy 1.5.0 (installed globally with Composer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation it says it only supports Mac and Linux. You are on Windows so that is likely why it is not working.

> Currently, Envoy only supports the Mac and Linux operating systems.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/envoy#introduction

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options for those who want to run Envoy on Windows:

1. Install [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) (WSL) and then Envoy via the WSL command line. It should run natively on Windows. As WSL has a feature to execute Linux binaries from within the Windows command line. You could also run it from the WSL command line.
2. Use [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead) for the project, then `vagrant ssh` into the Homestead virtual machine. Homestead has Envoy preinstalled.
3. Similar to using Homestead, you could just use any other virtual machine of your choice.
4. Use an alternative to Envoy that has support for Windows, such as [Deployer](https://deployer.org/)